# emacs org appt with sexp diary entries?

Tags: emacs

I am using org-mode version 8.2.5h on emacs-24.4. I recently set up appt.el following these instructions by scaramouche [1]. This works great for regular appointments in my org files but apparently not for appointments in my org files specified with sexp diary entries. For instance, I have the following entry in one of my org files:

```
%%(diary-float t 4 4) 10:00-10:30 Meeting with X.
```

This shows in my *Org Agenda* buffer but my-org-agenda-to-appt does not seem to recognize it and does not show and an alert. Any idea why this might be the case? Thanks!

[1] https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3844/good-methods-for-setting-up-alarms-audio-visual-triggered-by-org-mode-events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lack of other answers...

The diary sexp are parsed by the calendar/diary packages, and not by org. If you place the entry into your diary file, you can easily integrate it within org as well.

Add this entry to your org configuration:

```
(setq org-agenda-include-diary t)
```

When you add the appointment to your diary file they will appear within your org agenda.

- Chris

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Chris writes, note that the ORDER of diary's sexp entries changes depending upon the value of `calendar-date-style`.  See the Org manual's [footnote 67](http://orgmode.org/manual/Timestamps.html#FOOT67) which says, in part:

> Org mode users can resort to special versions
>   of these functions like `org-date` or `org-anniversary`.
>   These work just like the corresponding `diary-`
>   functions, but with stable ISO order of arguments
>   (year, month, day) wherever applicable, independent
>   of the value of `calendar-date-style`.